# How do I add a custom field to a model in Laravel?

Tags: php, activerecord, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm very new to Laravel and php frameworks in general, so sorry if I miss anything basic. I've created a new model called `Journey` in my application which extends the standard `Eloquent` model. What I've noticed is that I'm using my Journey model in two different Controllers and I'm duplicating a bit of code because of it.

Essentially, what I'm doing is I'm taking the title of a Journey and I'm formatting it with a custom class to clean the title (convert to lowercase, add hyphens, remove whitespace, etc) so I can append it to my page URLs.

In one controller, I'm calling:

```
$journey = Journey::find($id);
$journey->cleanURL = Url::clean($journey['name']); // This creates a new element/property with a clean string
```

And in the other, I'm calling:

```
$journeys = Journey::all();
foreach ($journeys as $journey) {
    $journey->cleanURL = URL::clean($journey['name']);
}
```

It would be inappropriate to add a fixed field to my database with the cleaned URL because I may change the title (which the cleaned URL is based on) at any time and I'd like the URL to update automatically in this event. However, saying this, I'm repeating myself by calling `Url::clean` twice.

What I'd like to do is write a method or alter an existing method, so that when I call `Journey::all()` or `Journey::find()` or any query-based method, the URL field is already present and filled. I've tried looking through some of the `Vendor/Eloquent` files, but they just make me confused.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) for this.

Add to your `Journey` model the following function:

```
public function getCleanUrlAttribute($value)
{
    return Url::clean($this->name);
}
```

Now you will be able to use:

```
$journey = Journey::find($id);
echo $journey->clean_url;
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the example and the link to the documentation. I didn't realize Accessors were a thing.